# refresh required to read inbox messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

[image]

Since a few days ago, when the red dot appears, indicating new messages, I can't click it. I always have to refresh the page first. Previously it worked fine. It's not the end of the world, but it's annoying. Bug?

Firefox 12.0 on XP SP3.

Comment: Workaround: Try clicking `Stack Exchange` instead of the red circle.

Comment: @Dennis - That doesn't seem to be a workaround. That's a solution! :-) (And I hadn't even tried that...)

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Sorry about that, some changes behind the scenes made the number not clickable under certain conditions.